# How could I modify the material slider (slider for a video) to have little comment icons at the right time intervals?

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material

Very new to Angular and material design. We're using a slider to represent where you are in a video on the page. I have comments on the page that have timestamps on them. What I want to do is to be able to show little comment icons along the time slider. Kinda a little like how soundcloud's player shows comments. Any suggestions on what I could do to accomplish this?

I already made a little component for the comment:

```
<mat-icon
     matTooltip = "{{comment.userName +  ':' + comment.text}}">
 </mat-icon>
```

What the slider and comments look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/klnDH.png

Thanks :)

Comment: How is it related to slider? The Comments are posted by users, Isn't it?

Comment: When a user comments, we keep track of what time in the video they are at. So if a user pauses at time A and comments, we can see time A in their comment. I want to add functionality so there will be comment icons along the slider at the right time intervals. So when there are a lot of comments, you can see visually where along the video they occur.